# How to apply join only it is required

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table (e.g. `Motherboard`) that contains the value that I'm looking for (e.g. `RAM`)... and let said that the Motherboard has 2 fields as PK, such as: `model_id` and `part_number`... 
if I had the model_id and all the RAM capacity are the same I don't care about the part numbers. The query will be something like:

```
SELECT Top 1 ram FROM Motherboard WHERE model_id = @model_id
```

Otherwise, we have to Join the table (e.g. `MyMBInfo`) that we stored that part_number.

```
SELECT Top 1 ram FROM Motherboard m
    LEFT JOIN MyMBInfo i ON SUBSTRING(i.model_id_and_other_stuff, 1, 9) = m.model_id and i.part_number = m.part_number
    WHERE model_id = @model_id
```

I can always use the second query, but it seems to be a quite expensive (join, substring, etc)... I have like millions of motherboards that need to figure out that Ram value.

I want to apply the first query and if it required, apply the second one, since (in my data) the probability that has different RAM for different parts are very rare (like 1%).

If you may know how to write a query that combine this two, something like:

```
SELECT Top 1 ram ... WHERE .... distinct_counter > 1 and part_number in SELECT ... FROM MyMBInfo WHERE...)
```

Or create a helper function.

Please share it.

Comment: Can I just say "eww" on the `SUBSTRING` join? :P `a LIKE b + '%'` should be way faster if you have `a` indexed. Even better, isolate the key into its own column - better to waste disk space than user's time - then do a regular left join; joining from a hacked `model_id_and_other_stuff` is quite suboptimal.

Comment: model_id_and_other_stuff as a fieldname is a clue that you need to redesign your table. You should not ever have multiple pieces of information stored in one field and then have to substring to get them out. And if you need to join to that field that is even worse!!! Please refactor to fix your very basic design flaw.

Answer (score 1):

A simple `IF` will do fine for this:

```
if (select count(distinct ram) from dbo.Motherboard WHERE model_id = @model_id) = 1
    select ram from dbo.Motherboard WHERE model_id = @model_id 
else 
    SELECT Top 1 ram FROM Motherboard m
            LEFT JOIN MyMBInfo i ON SUBSTRING(i.model_id_and_other_stuff, 1, 9) = m.model_id and i.part_number = m.part_number
            WHERE model_id = @model_id
```

The actual query execution plan will differ based on the condition, so you should only infer the necessary costs.

*Off-topic*: I'm very much with @Amadan on the (mis)use of `SUBSTRING` in your `JOIN`.